# Open a CATPart thru CAA and extract Features

Tags: catia, caa

I'm new to CAA development. I could able to customize CATIA using VB. Now, I'm going thru CAADoc. At last, I did Hello world which prints on the console window. Can someone put some segments of code which open a Part document and extract the features to excel? Please help me. Thanking you in advance.

Created Hello world. Though it's a Hello world, but the creation of Workspace, Framework, adding a component, etc. it's a too long process. But, felt okay.

Need a flow, after the creation of workspace and framework. How to Start coding, Where to start, where to refer for APIs, what are the headers to be added and a flow.

Comment: Could you please look at code shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205323/design-a-part-in-catia-by-clicking-an-excel-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my answer to another question there https://stackoverflow.com/a/35344085/2143734

do not mix 
- CAA which is a bunch of C++ API you can use (through the sole RADE/Enovia Studio plugin for Visual studio) to extend CATIA (along with SiMULIA and DELMIA, and pretty much all that share the CATIA frame) pretty thoroughly.
- And CATIA automation that allow you to automate actions in the software by writing vb/vba/vbs code

starting by the encyclopedia is right though, as both CAA and automation are documented there.